# Where are Windows SDK for Windows 8.1 includes?

Tags: visual-c++, sdk

I installed [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bg162891.aspx). I can't find any c++ headers neither in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1" nor in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A"

Where do they get installed to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows SDK installs to `Windows Kits`; e.g.,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include
```

Note that there are several directories under that location; you'll need to add the ones that you care about to your search path.